# Paths in master pages

Tags: asp.net-mvc, master-pages

I've started to work a bit with master pages for an ASP.net mvc site and I've come across a question.  When I link in a stylesheet on the master page it seems to update the path to the sheet correctly.  That is in the code I have

```
<link href="../../Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

but looking at the source once the page is fed to a browser I get

```
<link href="Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

which is perfect.  However the same path translation doesn't seem to work for script files.

```
<script src="../../Content/menu.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

just comes out as the same thing.  It still seems to work on a top level page but I suspect that is just the browser/web server correcting my error.  Is there a way to get the src path to be globbed too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<script src="<%= ResolveClientUrl("~/Content/menu.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Awesome, this is EXACTLY what has been missing in web pages since their inception

Comment: If this is in the <head> you may be better off using <%# and calling databind instead. <%= stops you from dynamically adding to the container, something lots of web controls do automatically

Answer (score 1):

Make an extension method. Here's a method:

```
public static string ResolveUrl(this HtmlHelper helper, string virtualUrl)
{
    HttpContextBase ctx = helper.ViewContext.HttpContext;
    string result = virtualUrl;

    if (virtualUrl.StartsWith("~/"))
    {
        virtualUrl = virtualUrl.Remove(0, 2);

        //get the site root
        string siteRoot = ctx.Request.ApplicationPath;

        if (!siteRoot.EndsWith("/"))
            siteRoot += "/";

        result = siteRoot + virtualUrl;
    }
    return result;
}
```

You can then write your script ref like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%= Html.ResolveUrl("~/Content/menu.js")%>"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead:

```
<link href="~/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: That won't work - the ~/ is replaced server side, so you need to add a runat="server" or wrap the location in a ResolveClientUrl

Answer (score 0):

or you can use BASE tag in you HEAD section of page. All you links then are relative to location entered in "base" tag, and you don't have to use "../../" and "~" stuff. Except links in CSS files (background url,etc), where links are relative to location of css file.